# What would cause random turning off

Tags: power-supply, dell-optiplex

My desktop (Dell Optiplex 790) is turning off about once a day. And it loses power fast, like if the plug was pulled from the wall.

I ran the diagnostics and it reports that all hardware is fine. However, there is no diagnostic test of the power supply.

Is this the power supply? And if so, any idea how to fin it on the Dell website? [A search there isn't useful.](https://pilot.search.dell.com/power%20supply%20optiplex%20790)

**Update:** To answer Pimp's items: If it's overheating won't I get some kind of message? Power should be fine as I have it in a new UPS, which is plugged into a dedicated 20 amp line. And I have another computer plugged in to the same outlet (separate UPS). I recently vacuumed the machine and everything looks ok.

Comment: This could be anything from an overheating PC turning off hardware to prevent overheating damage per smart sensors and such in this system, to a bad power supply, to electrical issues with the power source. Get the machine blown out for dust accumulation, plug it into a surge protector, and consider getting a voltmeter and looking over the specs of the power supply to confirm proper voltages and such as per the specs. Consider plugging the machine into a different power source / circuit temporarily too. Look at MOBO and confirm no heat damage, swollen capacitors, etc. too. Quick ideas only.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds like either CPU overheating or PSU problem.
You can test both with [OCCT](http://www.ocbase.com/). There are free and paid versions. Free is sufficient for most uses.
First, run the CPU stress test for about an hour and keep an eye on the temperature. If it is overheating, the computer will shut down itself to prevent damage.
If the computer didn't shut down, proceed to PSU stress test. If there is a problem, the computer will misbehave and probably shut down, as you described.